# Git files in Qt creator

Tags: qt, mavlink, qgroundcontrol

Sooo, I've been trying to use Qt creator and QGroundControl Open source repository and while trying to build my **qgroundcontrol.pro** file, the "Issues" bar shows this weird message:

```
unknown option: -
usage: git [-v | --version] [-h | --help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | -P | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           [--super-prefix=<path>] [--config-env=<name>=<envvar>]
           <command> [<args>]
```

Basicaly I think this is about not beeing able no read git files and it messing up the build.
Has this happen to anyone or am I just this lucky ? (:

I´ve tried searching for help and see the documentation for both Qt creator and QGroundControl and none have anything about this

Comment: Which platform? What version of git?

Comment: Nevermind, these error messages are not important